# Truffle's npm run build doesn't give me any .html and .js files in /build directory

Tags: truffle, dapps

I successfully deployed my contract with the truffle console. Then I wrote my DApp with the files index.html and app.js in the /app folder.

I attempted to build my codes for production by running the command

```
sudo npm run build
```

I went into my build folder but only see /contracts. From all my previous attempts, I would have seen the production versions of index.html and app.js in this folder that I can now copy to my web server. It strange that it didn't appear this time.

I am on Truffle v4.1.14.

By the way when I run

```
sudo npm run dev
```

I could see that index.html and app.js on localhost:8080.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I am using webpack by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My practice of deploying DApps has been to run

```
sudo npm run build
```

and then go to the /build directory to pick up the html and js files, then copy them into my /var/www/html/ directory so that I can access them externally through my webserver.

I realized that the current version of webpack obtained by running "truffle unbox webpack" no longer build the working .html and .js files in the /build directory. (WHY? It worked in July!)

Instead, the way to get your Dapp running on external IP address is as follows.

Edit webpack.config.js to add the following

```
devServer: {inline: true,host: '0.0.0.0',port: 8080,},
```

Then execute

```
sudo npm run dev
```

This will run your DApp on a development web server at your external IP address and you will be able to access it via e.g. http://:8080.

I still do not know how I could build for production, but am happy with this temporary solution for now.